Contribution ACL
Something about access control doesn't quite make sense to me.
On the "Contacts" page, if I go to the "Contributions" tab, I can see how many contributions the person has made (e.g. 21), but the page says "No contributions have been recorded from this contact." When I go to the "Activities" tab, I see all the contributions listed, there is a "View" button next to each one, but when I click on it, I get the message "You do not have access to this page.".
The weird thing is that I am experiencing this even with a user who is supposed to have all possible permissions (everything is checked on the permissions page). The error was reported by a user who does not have access to everything, but should have access to this. It is also true that the error occurs only with one type of financial type, but not with another.
How can I find out which right is missing or what I am not doing right?
Drupal 7 system, CiviCRM 5.77.0

Same here but with WordPress and Civi CRM 5.77.0, CiviContribute 5.77.0 and Financials ACL 5.77.0. :(

Just to add as well that from the Contact > Activities tab if I try to View the Contributions, as an administator, I get a access denied error. I can however create a contribution from the Contribution tab, it just doesn't show up.

Disabling "Access Control by Financial Type for Reports" (version 2.1) solved the problem. This is not a solution, but currently can use the system.

We were experiencing the same / a smimilar problem and created this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5537

If the system has Financial ACL extension enabled make sure the user role has correct permission to View/Add/Edit contribution based on Financial Type. You should see all the permission required under Permission page of the CMS
HTH
Pradeep

Yes, for development purposes are for all financial types the same access rights set (edit, view and add, but not delete). These rights are set for "all financial types", too, but these settings seems work for three of four financial type and not for the last one.

This is not a real solution, but disabling "Access Control by Financial Type for Reports" (version 2.1) makes Contribution list visible again.
